# Amount of days of intersected date ranges (Table)

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, intersection

I have 2 Tables:

**Table 1:**

```
Start Date | End Date   | Value
--------------------------------
dd.mm.yyyy | dd.mm.yyyy | 3
```

**Table 2:**

```
Start Date | End Date   | Value
--------------------------------
dd.mm.yyyy | dd.mm.yyyy | ????
```

The value of *Table 2* should be calculated the following way:

1. Find all rows in Table 1 one where the Start and End Date of Table 1
   intersect with the current rows Start and End Date of Table 2
2. For each of those rows, multiply the value of Table 1 with the amount of
   days that intersect
3. Sum up those values

---

**Example:**

**Table 1:**

```
Start Date | End Date   | Value
--------------------------------
01.01.2015 | 05.01.2015 | 3
03.01.2015 | 08.01.2015 | 6
```

**Table 2:**

```
Start Date | End Date   | Value
--------------------------------
02.01.2015 | 07.01.2015 | (4 * 3) + (5 * 6)
```

Where the value can be broken down the following way:

(4 days intersection in Table 1, Row 1 * Value of Row 1) + (5 days intersection in Table 1, Row 2 * Value of Row 2)

---

Unfortunately I have really NO idea on how to do that. The best would be if no VBA is involved (only formula).

Any ideas?

Thank you already!

Comment: Two things are crucial here: Excel must understand that the value of the cells are of the "date" format (verify the cell format for that), and once this is clear, you can use the ´days´ function for calculating the amount of days between two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic formula for getting the intersection of two date ranges is:-

```
MIN(End1,End2)-MAX(Start1,Start2)+1
```

If this turns out to be zero or negative there is no overlap.

I wanted to put this into an array formula because each result will have to be multiplied by the value in the same row of table 1 but MIN and MAX don't work so I ended up with a lot of IF statements:-

```
=SUM(IF(IF($B$2:$B$3<F2,$B$2:$B$3,F2)-IF($A$2:$A$3>E2,$A$2:$A$3,E2)<0,0,
IF($B$2:$B$3<F2,$B$2:$B$3,F2)-IF($A$2:$A$3>E2,$A$2:$A$3,E2)+1)*$C$2:$C$3)
```

where table 1 data is in A2:C3 and table 2 data is in E2:G2.

This needs to be entered in G2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Will post screen shot later]

Comment: Thank you very much! This gave me a hint on how to do it.